# Loading data from controller to chart Jquery/ MVC/ C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller code to return chart data to jquery.
UPDATE: I have modified the code as suggested, but still getting error.

```
 public JsonResult GetLeaveDataForPieChart(int user_id)
    {

        List<EmployeeLeaveHeader> elh1 = new List<EmployeeLeaveHeader>();
        List<ChartEvent> ch = new List<ChartEvent>();
        elh1 = itlbg1.EmployeeLeaveHeaders.Where(f => f.Employee_ID == user_id).ToList();

    foreach (var item in elh1)
    {
        ChartEvent ce = new ChartEvent();
        ce.value = (item.leaveAvailable * 100).ToString();
        ce.color = item.CompanyLeaves.LeaveTypes.color;
        ce.highlight = "#ffffff";
        ce.label = item.CompanyLeaves.LeaveTypes.typeDescription + " Leave Available";
        ch.Add(ce);

        ChartEvent ce1 = new ChartEvent();
        ce1.value = (item.leaveTaken * 100).ToString();
        ce1.color = item.CompanyLeaves.LeaveTypes.color_light;
        ce1.highlight = "#ffffff";
        ce1.label = item.CompanyLeaves.LeaveTypes.typeDescription + " Leave Taken";
        ch.Add(ce1);
    }



    return Json(ch, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

}
```

I need to retrieve data in jquery so that it is in the required format to be passed to pie data.

```
(document).ready(function () {

    user_id = $("#user_id_1").text();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Leave/GetLeaveDataForPieChart/',
        cache: false,
        data: { user_id: user_id },
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
            var PieData = $.each(data, function (idx, obj) {
                var leave = new Object();

                    leave.value = obj.value;
                    leave.color = obj.color;
                    leave.highlight = obj.highlight;
                    leave.label = obj.label;
                    alert(leave);
                    return leave;
                });

                    var pieOptions = {
    //pie options..

};

                pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
            }
        });
```

Can anyone explain how to convert the json data to javascript object to be passed to the pie chart?

Comment: var obj = eval(PieData)

Comment: what is meant by eval() here?
Kindly explain how it can be related to the updated code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you parse `JSON` string into object.

```
 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

here is how you use jquery to fetch the data and use it for your chart

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/<Controller>/GetLeaveDataForPieChart/',
        cache: false,
        data: {  user_id: <UserID> },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data, textStatus, xmlHttpRequest) {
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            //....
            //....
            //Chart
            //....
            //....
            //....
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do I have to parse the jsondata even if I return it as a json string from the controller?

Comment: @Nisal Upendra You are returning a string from your controller so yes, you do need to parse it. To return a json object from the controller, change the return type to ActionResult and return Json(jsonResult);

Comment: I did as you mentioned and the code for my chart now looks like this:
'
$.ajax({
        url: '/Leave/GetLeaveDataForPieChart/',
        cache: false,
        data: { user_id: user_id },
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            var pieChartCanvas = $("#pieChart").get(0).getContext("2d");
            var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
            var PieData = data;
            var pieOptions = {
               //options
            };
            pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
        }
    });
`
Still doesn't work.

Comment: Your answer explains convert the json data to javascript object to be passed to the pie chart, so I marked it as correct. My issue was with a missing js file and afterwards just passing the result data to PieData did the job. Thanks.

Comment: What is ***JSON.parse*** ? What I need javascript file(s) include?

Comment: JSON.parse() is an inbuilt function. It parses a JSON string to give you a JS object.

Comment: Thank you so much!